# Getting invalid opcode ba error while building Android project in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-binding

I'm trying to build a Xamarin Forms application while building/deploying the application i'm getting this error
[image]

Tried setting minsdk to 26 as well,did not work and I have a few Native Bindings as well, would that make any difference ??
I'm kinda stuck here, saw a couple of articles but that seems to be related to Android Native Java environment

any inputs would be deeply helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.Android does not "out of the box" support using new Java 1.8 constructs and down-converting them to 1.7 (at least in the slightly older releases) and that is the error that you are getting concerning the Java opcode `ba` (assuming one of your binding is using it).

You need to "desugar" the java 8 byte-code to 7:

- Use Java 8 language features : https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

So, add the following in your Xamarin.Android projects to enable byte-code transformations:

```
<AndroidEnableDesugar>true</AndroidEnableDesugar>
```

Comment: where should i add this again ??, in csproj right ??

Comment: yes, in the Xamarin.Android based projects (`.csproj`), add it in the default prop group. Also beware that some versions of Xamarin.Android did not desugar error free if multi-dex/proguard were not enabled, this has been fixed in the most recent versions

Comment: i'm getting an error like this now ,Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError :  com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/BaseMediaSource

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` sounds like the java class is stripped.... do you have the Mono linker and/or proguard enabled? I would post another question with the details

Comment: In the next Visual Studio 2019 / Visual Studio for Mac preview release, you will be able to use `d8` and `r8` which include `desugar` by default. This current method is using a very old version of `desugar` and will be deprecated in favor of using the new dex compiler (d8).https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/master/Documentation/guides/D8andR8.md#so-how-do-developers-use-it-what-are-sensible-msbuild-property-defaults

Answer (score 0):

In VisualStudio 2019 you can set the property in the Android project properties -> Android options -> Dex Compiler and choosing d8
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFlno.png)